# Filtering a List based on Optional Parameter Values

Tags: scala

Is there a more elegant way of filtering a list based on optional parameter values?

```
def f(dates: List[Date], start: Option[Long], end: Option[Long]): List[Date] = {
    (start, end) match {
        case (Some(s), Some(e)) =>  dates filter (_.getTime > s) filter (_.getTime < e)
        case (Some(s), None) => dates filter (_.getTime > s)
        case (None, Some(e)) => dates filter (_.getTime < e)
        case (None, None) => dates
    }
}
```

With three optional parameter values this would have 9 cases etc.

Comment: Just a sidenote: if you want to use multiple filters in a chain to a monadic construct (like a list), use a view to that list. dates.view.filter(...).filter(...) instead of dates.filter(...).filter(...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way would be as follows:

```
def f(dates: List[Date], start: Option[Long], end: Option[Long]): List[Date] =
  dates.filter( d => start.map(d.getTime > _).getOrElse(true) )
       .filter( d => end.map(d.getTime < _).getOrElse(true) )
```

or, even more succinct, you could use `forall` on the options:

```
def f(dates: List[Date], start: Option[Long], end: Option[Long]): List[Date] =
  dates.filter( d => start.forall(d.getTime > _) )
       .filter( d => end.forall(d.getTime < _) )
```

Answer (score 5):

In the case of an arbitrary amount of filters:

You could first change the parameter to List[Option[Date => Boolean]]. Then combine all filters that are actually there. Then apply the combined filter.

```
def f(dates : List[Date], filters : List[Option[Date => Boolean]]) = {
    val combFilter = filters.foldLeft((d : Date) => true)((comb, filter) => if(filter.isDefined) (d : Date) => comb(d) && filter.get(d) else comb)
    dates.filter(combFilter)
}
```

And assuming you have dates, start and end, you can call it like:

```
f(dates, List(start.map(s => _.getTime > s), end.map(e => _.getTime < e))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the key in your question is how to transform the parameters provided into a meaningful condition. Then you can scale up that method to any number of parameters (filtering conditions).

Using an intrinsic conversion (so, your code knows what to do with the parameter), I would approach like this:

```
def f(dates: List[Date], start: Option[Long], end: Option[Long]): List[Date] = {
      val filters = List(start.map(x=>{y:Long=>y>x}), end.map(x=>{y:Long=>y<x})).flatten
      dates.flatMap(date => if (filters.forall(filter =>  filter(date.getTime))) Some(date) else None)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with colleagues that it's better to have separate filters on every condition. For this purpose it's good to use the `.filter` method. However you also need to convert `Data` to `Long`. This can be done with an implicit converter:

```
implicit def dateToLong(d:Date) = d.getTime
```

Then you simply do filtering:

```
dates.view.filter(_ >= start).filter(_ <= finish)
```

If you still need optional filters then an implicit "pimp-my-library" can help

```
implicit class ListWithOptionalFilters[T](datas:List[T]){
  def filterOpt(f:Option[T=>Boolean]) = 
    datas.filter(d => f.forall(d))

}
```

Then you do it as follows:

```
def f(dates: List[Date], start: Option[Long], end: Option[Long]) = {
  val startFilter = start.map(l => (d:Date) => d>=l)
  val endFilter = end.map(l => (d:Date) => d<=l)
  dates.filterOpt(startFilter).filterOpt(endFilter)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val l1 = startDate.map { d => dates.filter(_ > d) }
val l2 = endDate.map { d => dates.filter(_ < d) }
l1.getOrElse(dates).intersect(l2.getOrElse(dates))
```

Comment: If l1/l2 is `None`, `dates` should be returned, not `Nil`. (Because you don't filter anything). And you only want to have the elements that both Lists contain, not the concatenation. (Since the elements should satisfy both conditions)

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case, I'd use:

```
def f(dates: List[Date], oStart: Option[Long], oEnd: Option[Long]): List[Date] = {
  val start = oStart.getOrElse(Long.MinValue)
  val end = oEnd.getOrElse(Long.MaxValue)
  dates.filter(date => date.getTime > start && date.getTime < end)
}
```

You could almost certainly generalise to some Min/Max Monoid for your start and end args, and combine it with Ordering to get a one-liner, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.